# Migration data between shards with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have the bellow MongoDB sharding with the following configuration :

- One front end sever
- One config sever
- 2 shards : shard01 and shard02
- A shard collection : collection01
- 2 zones/ 2 ranges :
- zone01  { "num" : 0  } -->> { "num" : 10 }
- zone02  { "num" : 11 } -->> { "num" : 20 }

Is it possible to migrate Data from zone01 to zone02 ?

I tried to remove range and recreate it again but i got duplicate data in the both shards/zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the process of migration was in progress after few time the data moves from shard01 to shard02 progressively, bellow the commands i used for that :

**1- Remove the current ranges**

```
sh.removeRangeFromZone("db2017.collection01", { num: 0  }, { num: 10 })
sh.removeRangeFromZone("db2017.collection01", { num: 11 }, { num: 20 })
```

**2- Recreate the new ranges with different zones :**

```
sh.addTagRange("db2017.collection01", { num: 1 }, { num: 10 }, "zone02")
sh.addTagRange("db2017.collection01", { num: 11 },{ num: 20 }, "zone01")
```

Just give sometime to your MongoDB it will migrate automatically your data between shards.